# How to hide ui button after clicking on it and show another button on place of that button swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller on which i have a button on right side named "EDIT", what i want to do is when user click on edit button then the button become hidden and a new button comes out at place of that button named "DONE". Here is code what i done so far -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var editBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var doneBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var welcomeBtn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // action when user taps on welcome button

    @IBAction func editBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    }

}
```

Comment: why don't you just change the title on click?

Comment: wow that's great, oh my god i don't where is my mind gone... thanks for this man. Really i am too much stupid.

Comment: no problem it happens .

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code like this -

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var editBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var doneBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var welcomeBtn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.doneBtn.isHidden = true

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // action when user taps on welcome button

    @IBAction func editBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        self.editBtn.isHidden = true
        self.doneBtn.isHidden = false

    }

    @IBAction func doneBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        self.doneBtn.isHidden = true
        self.editBtn.isHidden = false

    }
  }
```